# How to store RGB colors to a hashmap?

Tags: java, dictionary

I want to create a HashMap with RGB colors as keys. How should I store them to have best performance?
I mean, how does the "speed" of a hashmap refer to the object type of the key?

Should I use `Integer (018052175)` where each triplet would be one of RGB, `String (1234AF)` as HEX, or own Color class with `int r, g, b`? What might be the fastest implementation?

Comment: I would use [java.awt.Color](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color(float, float, float))

Comment: Most `String`s get interned in modern programming languages to produce fast lookups, so either Integer or String is probably fine. You should just try both then compare their performance. The other alternative is to use a `Color` object as the key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The speed of hash map is constrained by several essential properties of the `hashCode` and `equals` functions:

- How easy it is to calculate,
- How well is `hashCode` at distributing values into buckets, and
- How easy it is to compare values for equality

The `hashCode` function of a `String` is very good, and `String` caches its result to improve performance. However, equality check may be longer than with `Integer`.

The `Integer` class has a very hard-to-beat implementation of `hashCode` in terms of speed, but since the hash codes of similar colors would be close to each other, you may get more collisions with `Integer`s.

`Color` [is as fast as the `Integer`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/awt/Color.java.html), but it is also the most descriptive. I seriously doubt that choosing one of these three representations would hamper performance so significantly as to make a visible difference, so I would suggest going for the most descriptive choice, and then profile if necessary.

Comment: +1. This is exactly what I have in my mind, but was unable to frame as answer.

Comment: `Color` is just as fast as `Integer`

Comment: @SteveKuo Ah, you are absolutely right! I edited the answer, and added a link to the source of `Color.java`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The only difference is going to be the speed of the hashcode/equals functions, and an Integer should be the fastest, though it is unlikely to be a bottleneck in any case. You should probably use whatever is going to be most convenient elsewhere in the code.

Comment: `Color.hashCode()` is just as fast as `Integer`'s

Answer (score 1):

`HashMap` is based on `hashCode()` and [`Integer.hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#hashCode%28%29) is as fast as you can get (it's an identity function):

> a hash code value for this object, equal to the primitive `int` value represented by this `Integer` object.

<del>Thus go for `Integer` representing 24-bit RGB value.</del> However it turns out [`Color.hashCode()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/Color.java#Color.hashCode%28%29) is as fast, and since `Color` class is much more expressive and readable than `Integer`, use `Color` class instead.

Comment: `Color.hashCode()` is just as fast

Answer (score 0):

Java has a built in class for storing color called [Color](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html).

I would go and make optimizations (using integer will not be much faster I guess) unless you actually see its a bottleneck

Answer (score 0):

Use `Integer`s, and get them with `new Color(r, g, b).getRGB()`.

To get the color from an integer, just use `new Color(hashmap.get(index))`.

Answer (score 0):

`Integer.hashCode()` is no faster than `Color.hashCode()`. `java.awt.Color`'s `hashCode` implementation (Java 1.6):

```
/**
 * Computes the hash code for this <code>Color</code>.
 * @return     a hash code value for this object.
 * @since      JDK1.0
 */
public int hashCode() {
    return value;
}
```

`equals` for both are also equivalent. So in your case I'd use `Color` as it better conveys the semantics.