# Java, how to store multiple integers, separated by comma, into one variable

Tags: java, processing

In Java, I want to setup a variable that can store multiple integers (RGB values) and integers are separated by comma.
For example, my current code is like

```
background(255,255,0);  // This changes my GUI background color to yellow.
```

The code I want is

```
type yellow = (Here goes the yellow's RGB value 255,255,0)
background(yellow);
```

My question is how to setup the variable *yellow* so it can replace the actual RGB values.
Thank you.

Comment: Take a string varible which has color rgb format. when required then split by comma `,` and use it

Comment: A variable stores only one value. But an array can store multiple values. Ex `a[0], a[1], a[2]`.

Comment: @Satya it's not 'separated by comma' then. I assume he's looking for a String int a + ', ' + int b + ..

Comment: @Stultuske Yes Op looking for comma separated values. But here not possible with string.

Comment: It depends how the **background** method is defined - if it takes just 3 integers I suppose you can not pass there just one variable (there is no "autounpacking" on method calling level in Java)

Comment: Even though your values are integers in pure sense, I guess you are not going to perform any arithmetic operations ( addition , multiplication etc ) on those so it doesn't make sense to store as integers. Its more of a codification as `Enums` or `Strings` or `HashMaps` or as a custom class like AWT `Color` etc

Comment: Can you not just use a `java.awt.Color` instance?

Comment: see these questions , [question1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976414/how-to-store-rgb-colors-to-a-hashmap), [question2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19926933/how-to-store-rgb-values-of-each-pixel-in-array), [question3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19857861/enum-to-store-rgb-strings) and similar other questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the answers you got so far somehow solve the problem you described.
But the problem is: they are not really helpful.

**Never** put information into strings and rely on parsing them. If you really want to do that; then you really do not need all the overhead of a statically compiled language like java. Then you are much better of using languages like python, ruby ... which allow you to handle "stringified" information much easier.

What you want to do is: learn about object orientation. So, you want to represent colors. Then model a class that represents a color. That could look somehow like:

```
public class Color {
  private final int r, g, b;
  public Color(int r, ... {
    this.r = r
```

and so on. Then you can write down a color like

```
Color yellow = new Color(255,255,0)
```

Heck; you could even start and declare **constants** representing useful predefined colors.

You know, like the existing Java AWT Color [class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html).

So: please take the time to learn and understand the concepts I am talking about; and keep in mind: using strings for such purposes is **absolutely bad**.

Comment: This is a fine general answer, but this question is about [tag:processing] which has its own `color` type. See my answer for more info.

Comment: Thanks; I did overlook that.

Answer (score 3):

Processing already has a `color` type that you should use- **you should not create your own or use `java.awt.Color`!**

Instead, just use the existing `color` type and `color()` function:

```
color yellow = color(255, 255, 0);
background(yellow);
```

More info can be found in [the Processing reference](https://www.processing.org/reference/color_datatype.html).

Answer (score -1):

Well I think you had some good answers for your question. But just to add, you mentioned that your working on a GUI program, I am guessing your using swings, you can simply call the method

```
setBackground(Color.yellow);
```

on all the objects that are created using classes that inherit from Component.

Comment: This question is about [tag:processing], not Swing.